# Xgboost - How to use feature_importances_ with XGBRegressor()?

Tags: python, regression, xgboost

How could we get `feature_importances` when we are performing regression with `XGBRegressor()`?

There is something like `XGBClassifier().feature_importances_`?

Comment: (XGBClassifier().feature_importances_) it is right , where is the problem ??

Comment: @Abhishek I can't use `feature_importances_` with `XGBRegressor()`, because it works only with `XGBClassifier()`.

Comment: I had to use: model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have solved this issue by:

`model.booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')`

Comment: But mine returned an error : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: A bit off-topic, have you tried github.com/slundberg/shap for feature importance? It looks a bit complicated at first, but it is better than normal feature importance.

Comment: for me: `model.get_score(importance_type='weight')`

Comment: @TonyWang try `model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')` instead.

Comment: Sndn's solution worked for me as on 04-Sep-2019

Answer (score 13):

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
model = XGBClassifier.fit(X,y)

# importance_type = ['weight', 'gain', 'cover', 'total_gain', 'total_cover']
model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')
```

However, the method below also returns feature importance's and that have different values to any of the "importance_type" options in the method above. This was raised in [this github issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3367), but there is no answer [as of Jan 2019].

```
model.feature_importances_
```

Comment: The values in the list `feature_importances_` equal the values in the dict `get_score(importance_type='weight')` where each element is divided by the sum of elements.

Comment: Which importance_type is equivalent to the sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor version of feature_importances_? My suspicion is total_gain

Answer (score 3):

In the past the Scikit-Learn wrapper `XGBRegressor` and `XGBClassifier` should get the feature importance using `model.booster().get_score()`. Not sure from which version but now in `xgboost 0.71` we can access it using

```
model.feature_importances_
```

Comment: I'm using `from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor` in version 0.72.1 and this worked for me.  Thanks!