# XGBoost: Quantifying Feature Importances

Tags: python, xgboost, predictor-importance

I need to quantify the importance of the features in my model. However, when I use XGBoost to do this, I get completely different results depending on whether I use the variable importance plot or the feature importances.

For example, if I use `model.feature_importances_` versus `xgb.plot_importance(model)` I get values that do not align. Presumably the feature importance plot uses the feature importances, bu the numpy array `feature_importances` do not directly correspond to the indexes that are returned from the `plot_importance` function.

Here is what the plot looks like:

[image]

But this is the output of `model.feature_importances_` gives entirely different values:

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.13636364,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.01136364,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.07386363,
        0.03409091,  0.        ,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.01704546,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.05681818,  0.15909091,  0.0625    ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.10227273,  0.        ,  0.07386363,
        0.01704546,  0.05113636,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.02272727,  0.        ,  0.01136364,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.11363637,  0.        ,  0.01704546,  0.01136364,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ], dtype=float32)
```

If I just try to grab Feature 81 (`model.feature_importances_[81]`), I get:`0.051136363`. However `model.feature_importances_.argmax()` returns `72`.

So the values do not correspond to each other and I am unsure about what to make of this.

**Does anyone know why these values are not concordant?**

Comment: Welcome to the site! XGBoost produces multiple measures of feature "importance" (3 actually). Check that the __same type__ of feature importances are being output.

Comment: Good idea @bradS. I'll take a closer look. Any idea how to specify the type in for `model.feature_importances_`? I know how to specify it with `xgb.plot_importances(model)`, but it is not clear if you can change it with the `.feature_importances_` method.

Comment: [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19882/xgboost-how-to-use-feature-importances-with-xgbregressor) suggests using `model.booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')`... I'd wager changing the `importance_type` will solve your issue.

Answer (score 15):

In `xgboost 0.7.post3`:

1. `XGBRegressor.feature_importances_` returns weights that sum up to one.
2. `XGBRegressor.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')` returns occurrences of the features in splits. If you divide these occurrences by their sum, you'll get Item 1. Except here, features with 0 importance will be excluded.
3. `xgboost.plot_importance(XGBRegressor.get_booster())` plots the values of Item 2: the number of occurrences in splits.
4. `XGBRegressor.get_booster().get_fscore()` is the same as `XGBRegressor.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')`

Method `get_score` returns other importance scores as well. Check the argument [`importance_type`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.get_score).

In `xgboost 0.81`, `XGBRegressor.feature_importances_` now returns *gains* by default, i.e., the equivalent of `get_score(importance_type='gain')`. See `importance_type` in [`XGBRegressor`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor).

So, for importance scores, better stick to the function `get_score` with an explicit `importance_type` parameter.

Also, check [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12318/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-of-xgboost-importance) for the interpretation of the `importance_type` parameter: "weight", "gain", and "cover".

Comment: Thanks for this! It was driving me crazy that everything said feature_importances_ was weight but it seemed to be gain.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger!